# How to Manually Set Assembly Version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This one is giving me such a headache.  We used to put things in the project properties under `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]` I am totally fine with change so I do not care where it is.  I understand they are going to a new standard for versions as well, also totally fine.

Plenty of documents out there point to the `project.json` file which is clearly a waste as this is no longer a legit file.  More recent say add the following to your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.2.3</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix>alpha</VersionSuffix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Also a total waste.  Only because I can not seem to be able to read it. The following always gives me `1.0.0.0`.

```
PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationVersion
```

Not to mention when I right-click in `File Explorer` and click `Properties`, then `Details` tab also always says `1.0.0.0`.

So, how I can set the version of each assembly within my solution AND then read them later at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this started working when .Net Core **2.0** came out.  When you right-click on the **Project** and then click **Properties** there is a UI for it as seen below:

[image: UI of Project Properties]

The `Package Version`, `Assembly Version` and `Assembly File Version` correspond to the `Version`, `AssemblyVersion` and `FileVersion` settings in the `.csproj` file respectively:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Version>1.1.0</Version>
  <AssemblyVersion>1.1.0.9</AssemblyVersion>
  <FileVersion>1.1.0.9</FileVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I then created a utility method in each project of my solution that does the following:

```
public static VersionInformationModel GetVersionInformation() {
  var Result = new VersionInformationModel {
    Version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString(),
    BuildDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    Configuration = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyConfigurationAttribute>().Configuration,
    TargetFramework = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute>().FrameworkName,
  };

  return Result;
}
```

So on an admin page of my site, I can know when version and other particulars about each project as it stands on whatever server I am looking at.

Answer (score 4):

On method is to set either of these values in your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version>1.3.5.7</Version>
    <FileVersion>2.4.6.8</FileVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And read them like this:

```
var fileVersion = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
    .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>()
    .Version;

var informationalVersion = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
    .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
    .InformationalVersion;
```

It's worth noting that setting these value in the .csproj file does autogenerate (so don't try to edit it) a file similar to the legacy `AssemblyInfo.cs` containing something like this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Reflection;

//snip    
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("2.4.6.8")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("1.2.3")]

// Generated by the MSBuild WriteCodeFragment class.
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this did not work.  I put the `<PropertyGroup>` in as the second `<PropertyGroup>` right after the `TargetFramework` one of `netcoreapp1.1` and both `fileVersion` and `informationalVersion` came back as `1.0.0.0` and the File Explorer | Properties | Details also said `1.0.0.0`.  Am I on some wrong version or .Net Core or what?  Ugh!

Comment: Well you don't need a new property group, just put those values in with the target framework.

Comment: Moving the versions to the first `PropertyGroup` changed nothing.  I get your point of not changing autogenerated files, but I do not even see the AssemblyInfo.cs file anywhere.  Even after a Rebuild.  I must be missing something?

Comment: The autogenerated file is kinda hidden away in `obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\YourProject.AssemblyInfo.cs`

Comment: I do see it there, and yes, it is still 1.0.0.0.  Is this a `netcoreapp2.0` thing?

Comment: No, it's a 1.1 thing. Can you set the versions in the project properties?

Comment: I was initially looking for it when I right-click on the Project name and then click Properties.  I no longer see the ... for Assembly info.  If I expand out the Properties node in Solution Explorer I see nothing but Publish Profiles and launchSettings.json.

Comment: So @DavidG, any thoughts?  I can move this to a chat if necessary?

Comment: I'm not really sure what else I could do to help other than supply example working code. How are you building? Which IDE? Do you have multiple projects? Perhaps you could give more information?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.2.  I have an MVC project, a DataContext project and then an Entities project.  It is .Net Core 1.1. C# connecting to a SQL server database using Entity Framework Core. Currently building for Any CPU in Debug mode.